# jquery not selecting option tags when value contains space

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Do I need to somehow escape a space when using jquery to select with contains/find?

I am mocking this up so pardon the typos...
If I have a SELECT tag that has some options

```
<select title="animals">
<option value="Dog Black">Dog Black</option>
<option value="Cat Black">Cat Black</option>
<option value="Dog Brown">Dog Brown</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to find the options in this select using jquery.  but it appears that the "find" method or "contains" function fails when the value being passed to search for contains a space.  For example:

The following returns a size of 2:

```
$('*[title="animals"]').find("option:contains('Dog')").size()
```

But this returns 0 whre I would expect 2 as well:

```
$('*[title="animals"]').find("option:contains('Dog B')").size()
```

My guess is that this has something to do with the selector and it is looking for a child element with "B" or something but Im not really sure.

Comment: Was a bug in 1.2.6 version of jquery, workgin fine on 1.3.2...Sorry :)

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I have a mix of text/value with and without spaces in the drop down. On changing the selection, the non-spaces value is retrieved correctly using JavaScript/jQuery but if the value has space, it returns the first value in the list and even the selected index is 0. This post also talks about the same issue - http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/748140-jquery-custom-selectbox-not-passing-value-with-spaces/

Comment: Yes it seems this is a bug. I have found a solution and adding it to pointed site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this exact code in a page with essentially nothing else in it, and it returns 2 on both find() functions in all of my browsers.  Perhaps there is something else in your code interfering with your results?  Maybe you're stashing the results somewhere and losing track of the value, or overwriting it?

Or maybe you already figured out the problem.  :p

Comment: Thanks for testing It was a bug in the 1.2.6 version of jquery.  1.3.2 works fine.  Ill give you the credit for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry after banging my head for hours I found a a bug elsewhere in the code after posting this that caused the issue, closing this out